# allign string to the right of the screen in isearch echo area

Tags: isearch, echo-area

Since emacs 27.1 isearch can show how many matches there are in the buffer.
I enabled it like this:

```
(setq isearch-lazy-highlight t
      isearch-lazy-count t
      lazy-count-prefix-format ""
      lazy-count-suffix-format " (%s of %s matches)")
```

This will give me the following string in the echo area (when searching for "test"):

```
I-search: test (2 of 4 matches)
```

I find that helpful, but distracting.
The count is too close to the area where I type.
I would rather have it right aligned in the echo area, like this:

```
I-search: test                                                               (2 of 4 matches)
```

I can just add spaces to `lazy-count-suffix-format`, but this would be a bad solution.
Especially because the right number of spaces depends on multiple things:

- the length of the string I search for
- the length of the the prompt from I-search (depending on different factors it can be different from "I-search: "
- the length of the representation of the number of matches

So how can I allign the string "(%s of %s matches)" to the right?

Comment: I take it you don't like the default behavior, which is to show `2/4 Isearch: `? To my mind that's the least distracting: everything after the (pseudo-) prompt `Isearch: ` corresponds to your *search pattern* -- no matter how complex that search pattern is, and whether or not it includes multiple lines (embedded newline chars).

Comment: @Drew You are right, I don't like that. I find that distracting because it updates as I type (which is good in itself). It means that text changes close to where I type, so it draws my attention to it. It also means that my input is moving left and right when the numbers change their magnitude.